# Question about async handling in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have a question that has been bothering me for a long time. I would greatly appreciate your help!

Let's imagine a situation like this:

> You entered a function by a command. In this particular function, there is a loop that takes a long time to finish, or worse, it is actually an infinite loop. The question is, how can you abort this loop or function so that the bot can handle other requests?

An example would be like this:

```py
def function(update, context):
  counter = 0
  message = update.message.reply_text(str(counter))

  while True:
    counter += 1
    message = message.edit_text(text = str(counter))
    time.sleep(1)

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("main", function))
```

After user enters this function by "/main", he or she gets a message that includes a number, which the number increases every second and this will take forever to finish.

Something that I have tried:

- Design another `MessageHandler`, if user sends some keywords like "stop", it changes the value of a global variable. In the loop, it checks if this variable is `True` every time before it adds the number, if it was `False`, it breaks.

  However, the MessageHandler won't detect this message before the loop has actually ended, so this is meaningless.
- Include a `InlineKeyboard` in the message, with a button called "Stop". Design another `CallbackQueryHandler` to handle this button.

  Similarly, CallbackQueryHandler will only receive the callback after the loop was finished. This can be verified if I set a manual `break` when the counter hits a number like 5 or something.

I was thinking if I could design some kind of abort function that runs asynchronously, but I am personally not very familiar with async in Python. After some trials like setting `async def` or `CallbackQueryHandler(query_handle, run_async = True)`, I still failed to produce this effect.

I noticed there is a decorator called `from telegram.ext.dispatcher import run_async`, does that help? Or, is there any other way to realize this result?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: This question was also asked at https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/discussions/2904

Comment: Please note that all of this question is no longer a thing in PTB v20 with the async release, and people should generally learn the asynchronous programming skills, you will benefit a lot!

Answer (score 7):

By default `Dispatcher` handles the incoming updates one by one. That's why your first two approaches can't work. What you can do is run the loops in a standalone thread. This is in fact, what the `run_async` parameter is there for - it has nothing to do with `asyncio` programming. See [this wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Performance-Optimizations#multithreading) for detailed information about `run_async`. Also note that the next major version of PTB will introduce `asyncio` to PTB - see [this announcement](https://t.me/pythontelegrambotgroup/430620).

I'd like to point out that a `while` loop + `time.sleep()` might not be the best idea anyway, especially if the sleep-time is significant. An alternative would be to schedule a repeating job. PTB has the built-in [`JobQueue`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) for that.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to apply those asap, and I think that I really should spend sometime learning on `asyncio` programming as more of these wrappers are updating to it, and a lot of code changing is going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Examples how to configure handlers to be run in anync mode for `python-telegram-bot==13.13` (`run_async=True` is passed to handlers):

```
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler(["zip_and_send_all_logs", "zsal"],
                                      zip_and_send_all_logs_cmd, run_async=True))
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command,
                                      run_sh_cmd_for_text_msg, run_async=True))
```

Also there is `@run_async` decorator function in

```
from telegram.ext.dispatcher import run_async
```

which can be used to mark handler to be run in async mode. But this decorator was deprecated. Recommended way is to pass `run_async` parameter to handlers. Its default value is `False`.

Related question: [Is python-telegram-bot suitable for async job? #877](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/877)